# Delay in updating UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've a such situation:
I get data from API and this data comes pretty shortly. When I push them in NSLogs, they are there once I request. After that I parse them (from JSON) and try to set in controls like UILabel or UIImageView (in case of image). I think I checked the time delay of data pushing to the last point - I mean I was trying to get NSLog in method, where I get data, where parsing etc. and finally in method setText in subclass of UILabel.

**What's the problem?** Content in NSLogs comes really shortly, but in UI is updated after... 10-20 sec. !! What might be the reason?

Piece of exemplary code

```
{
[[contentView movieTitle] setText:movieTitle];
[[contentView movieYear] setText:movieYear];
[[contentView movieGenres] setText:movieGenres];
[[contentView movieDuration] setText:movieTime];
[[contentView movieDescription] setText:movieDescription];
[[contentView movieStarringName] setText:movieStarring];
[[contentView movieDirectorName] setText:movieDirector];

NSLog(@"--- %@", [contentView movieTitle].text);
}
```

And this NSLog comes in a second, but [contentView movieTitle] in UI changes itself after 10-20 secs.

I request data asynchronously.
All properties like contentView or movieTitle, movieGenres etc. are (nonatomic, retain).

Comment: Is this code running on the background thread?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely doing your UI updating in a background thread (Where you get the return from the webservice, or parsing the JSON).  In order to update your UI in a timely mannar (and without possibly crashing the app) do your updates in the main thread.  This can be done in a few ways.  The easiest (for me at least) is calling `dispatch_async`.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[contentView movieTitle] setText:movieTitle];
        [[contentView movieYear] setText:movieYear];
        [[contentView movieGenres] setText:movieGenres];
        [[contentView movieDuration] setText:movieTime];
        [[contentView movieDescription] setText:movieDescription];
        [[contentView movieStarringName] setText:movieStarring];
        [[contentView movieDirectorName] setText:movieDirector];
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solutions thanks to http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1473390

Instead of creating new queue I had to get reference from mainQueue.

Comment: That will likely block your UI while the data is retrieved and parsed.  The best method would be to keep your queue out of the main thread, but call back into the main thread when you want to update your user interface.